# Returning a pair type in C++ function prevents complation

Tags: c++, std-pair

I have a function in C++ with the following header:

```
int DECLSPEC __cdecl HandleUpdate(uint8_t* MessageBuffer, uint32_t MessageLength );
```

However, I do not want this function to return an `int`, I now need it to return a `std::pair<uint8_t*, uint32_t>*`.

Changing **literally only the return type** (and adding the return value in the function) in the `.h` and `.cpp` file throws these errors, despite the code compiling correctly when the return type is a standard type (`int`, `bool`, `void`):

```
//all of these errors pertain to the code snippets I have made available

error C2059: syntax error: '__declspec(dllexport)'                 //on the declaration in the header file
error C2238: unexpected token(s) preceding ';'                     //on the declaration in the header file
error C2059: syntax error: '__declspec(dllexport)'                 // on `std` in the return type in the .cpp file
error C2039: 'HandleUpdate': is not a member of 'EACServer'        //in the .cpp file
error C2143: syntax error: missing ';' before '{'                  //on opening curly bracket of .cpp file function
error C2447: '{': missing function header (old-style formal list?) //on opening curly bracket of .cpp file function
```

The current state of the code:

```cpp
//HEADER
std::pair<uint8_t*, uint32_t>* DECLSPEC __cdecl HandleUpdate(uint8_t* MessageBuffer, uint32_t MessageLength) const;

//CPP
std::pair<uint8_t*, uint32_t>* DECLSPEC __cdecl EACServer::HandleUpdate(uint8_t* MessageBuffer, uint32_t MessageLength)
{
    //do some cool stuff
    std::pair<uint8_t*, uint32_t> tmp( MessageBuffer, MessageLength );
    this->messageArray[this->messagesInArray] = tmp;
    this->messagesInArray += 1;
    return this->messageArray;
}
```

I'm using VS 2017 and compiling to Release x64 on a Windows 10 x64 machine.

Is there something wrong with the way I defined the return type?

All advice is greatly appreciated.

> ***MINIMUM REPRODUCIBLE EXAMPLE***

**Header file**

```
// Foo.h
#pragma once
#ifndef Foo_H
#define Foo_H

#include <stdint.h>
#include <string>
#include <utility>

class Foo:
{
public:
    std::pair<uint8_t*, uint32_t>* DECLSPEC __cdecl HandleUpdate( uint8_t* 
    MessageBuffer,uint32_t MessageLength );
private:
    mutable std::pair<uint8_t*, uint32_t>* messageArray;
    mutable int messagesInArray;
}
```

**.CPP file:**

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include <iostream>

#include "Foo.h"

typedef int( __cdecl* MYPROC )( LPWSTR );

std::pair<uint8_t*, uint32_t>* DECLSPEC __cdecl EACServer::HandleUpdate(                                               uint8_t* MessageBuffer, uint32_t MessageLength )
{
    std::pair<uint8_t*, uint32_t> tmp( MessageBuffer, MessageLength );
    this->messageArray[this->messagesInArray] = tmp;
    this->messagesInArray += 1;
return this->messageArray;
}

int main()
{
Foo bar = Foo();
uint8_t* MessageBuffer = 0;
uint32_t MessageLength = 0;
std::pair<uint8_t*, uint32_t>* result = bar.HandleUpdate(MessageBuffer, MessageLength);
}
```

Comment: Please provide a [mcve].

Comment: *Changing literally only the return type* -- Then that's wrong if that's all you did.  You forgot to include the header where `std::pair` is defined.

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/cpp/declspec?view=msvc-160 "The __declspec keywords should be placed at the beginning of a simple declaration. The compiler ignores, without warning, any __declspec keywords placed after * or & and in front of the variable identifier in a declaration."

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie isn't it defined in `<utility>`? I have updated my post to show the header file (cpp is in progress) - it was already included

Comment: @ThomasSablik So it's he `*` throwing it off? What do I need to do differently to return a pointer?

Comment: The function declaration is `const` but the function definition is not. Please provide one [mcve] and not different snippets.

Comment: Remove `__decslspec(dllexport)` from definition in `.cpp`. And put it in the beginning of the line. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/build/exporting-from-a-dll-using-declspec-dllexport?view=msvc-160

Comment: @4xy So simple yet so effective - I didn't know that keyword could be moved. You can post that as an answer if you want :) thank you

Comment: @Jessica Chambers You are welcome

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remove `__decslspec(dllexport)` from definition in `.cpp`. And put it in the beginning of the line.

[Exporting from a DLL Using __declspec(dllexport)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/build/exporting-from-a-dll-using-declspec-dllexport?view=msvc-160)